# copy from column A (Sheet1) to Column B (Sheet2) below previous data of column B

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

How to copy data from column A (Sheet1) to column B (Sheet2) without modifying previous data on colunm B? Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this the other day?  Question was "vba excel 2010 copy data to another empty column sheet"?  How does this question differ?

Comment: Yesterday I asked how to put data in sequencial empty columns. Now I want to know how copy data to the same column without modifying precedent data of colunm B.

Comment: It would be best if you laid out the scenario.  For example, data in cells A1, A2, A3 in Sheet1 - copy to Sheet 2 B1, B2, B3 but only if B1, B2, and B3 are empty.  Then if there are values in B1, B2, B3 what should happen?  Not copy?  Or put in in B4, B5, B6 (or other empty cells).

Comment: Put in B4, B5 ,B6 etc. A stack column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic answer that does not replace the cells but looks for the next empty ones.  I've tried to put comments in that will help understand it.

```
Sub CopySheet1toSheet2()

    Dim CurrRow As Integer
    Dim CurrCol As Integer
    Dim TargetRow As Integer
    Dim TargetCol As Integer

    Dim Sheet1 As String
    Dim Sheet2 As String

    Sheet1 = "Sheet1" ' name to your source sheet name
    Sheet2 = "Sheet2" ' change to your target sheet name
    CurrRow = 1
    CurrCol = 1 ' This is column A

    TargetRow = 1
    TargetCol = 2 ' This is column B

    ' Cycle through all rows in Col A until empty field reached
    While Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(CurrRow, CurrCol) <> ""

        ' See if there's a value in column B in the same row - if so, go to the next row
        While Sheets(Sheet2).Cells(TargetRow, TargetCol) <> ""
            TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
        Wend

        ' Copy the value from the source to the target
        Sheets(Sheet2).Cells(TargetRow, TargetCol) = Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(CurrRow, CurrCol)

        ' Move to the next source and target rows
        CurrRow = CurrRow + 1
        TargetRow = TargetRow + 1

    Wend

End Sub
```